# how to capture value returned from method in thread execution c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[12];
int temp;


 for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length - 1; i++)
 {
       temp = i;
       threads[temp] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=>     test(test1[temp],"start", temp)));
       threads[temp].Start();
       //threads[temp].Join();
 }



for(int i=0; i<threads.Length-1; i++)
{
    threads[i].Join();
}
```

//Need to capture the response returned from method executed"test1" in thread.

Comment: What problem do you want to solve in common?

Comment: Provide the code for `test()` and `test1()`, at least an outline. And how do you want the results? There are 12 of them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Task<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) (if you're on .NET 4+), which has a return value. You could also use events to get notified when the thread is done with doing whatever it does and get the returned value that way.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this. NugGet "Rx-Main".

```
var query = 
    Observable
        .Range(0, 12)
        .SelectMany(n => Observable
            .Start(() => new
            {
                n,
                r = test(test1[n], "start", n)
            }))
        .ToArray()
        .Select(xs => xs
            .OrderBy(x => x.n)
            .Select(x => x.r)
            .ToArray());

query.Subscribe(rs =>
{
    /* do something with the results */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start the thread using another [ctor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h2f2459(v=vs.110).aspx) overload where you can start the thread and pass an object to that thread. The thread would then save the result in a field of that object. The main thread could after the call to `Join` retrieve the results from all those objects. You could have an array of 12 objects each of them passed to one thread. Or you could have an array of 12 classes, each class encapsulating one thread and the corresponding object that wraps the result:

```
public class ThreadResult
{
    public int Result {get; set;}
}
```

However, today you have better choices than raw threads. Take a look at TPL (Task Parallel Library) and async / await in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a shared state, in this case you have to lock every access to the shared objects inside the thread method:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[12];

int temp;
string msg = "";
List<string> results = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
{
    temp = i;

    threads[temp] = new Thread(() =>
    {
        lock (results)
        {
            lock (msg)
            {
                msg = "Hello from Thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                results.Add(msg);
            }                        
        }
    });

    threads[temp].Start();
}


for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
{
    threads[i].Join();
}
```